# Why is the antenna on the Mazda5 off-center?

Tags: mazda, automotive-design

Does anyone know why the antenna on the Mazda5 is not centered on the back of the vehicle?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not found anything definitive (only speculation on forums), but it appears the reason they offset the antenna is so it is more easily accessible for removal (such as when going through an automated car wash). If you look at this picture, you can see how far forward it is from the back of the car. Reaching up from the back to remove it could prove daunting. Looking at it, you can see that there was no way to move it back as it would interfere with the operation of the lift gate, so moving it to one side seems logical for this reason.

[image: Picture of a Mazda5 from Mazda website]

Comment: Interesting. But, the larger SUVs like the CX-5 have it centered (http://images.mazdausa.com/MusaWeb/musa2/images/garage/gallery/2014/cx5/pho_gallery_CX5_ext10.jpg)

Comment: @EliLansey ... but as the picture shows, the antenna on the CX-5 is just a stubbie. It does not stick up like the Mazda5's does. There is no reason to remove on that. I've read where others have replaced the pointy one on the Mazda5 with a "shark fin" type, which eliminates the pointer.